# How to take advantage of lambda expression with optionals

Tags: java, lambda, refactoring, guava, option-type

I am trying to find a clean and code efficient way to apply the transform method in guava optional to create an object, I am working with Java 8 with Guava.

In one place of the code, I have an optional created . 
`Optional<Object> optional = Optional.of(objFromDatabase)`

And in another area I am trying to create a new object with this optional. The best thing I could think of is

```
    if (optional.isPresent()) {
        Object obj = optional.get();
        NewObject newObj = obj.createNewObj(); //throws IOException, newobj to be returned
    } else { throw new IOException() }
```

But this is cumbersome, and I'm hoping to learn a bit more about optionals and lambda expressions.

Any good ideas out there?

Answer (score 3):

No one really gave a code answer, so here's one.

First, create a method that maps the object and handles the checked exception (by wrapping it in a unchecked exception).

```
private NewObject uncheckedCreateNewObject(Object o) {
  try {
    return o.createNewObject();
  } catch (IOException e) {
    throw new UncheckedIOException(e);
  }
}
```

Then, just do a normal mapping:

```
NewObject newObject = Optional.of(objFromDatabase).toJavaUtil()
  .map(this::uncheckedCreateNewObject)
  .orElseThrow(IOException::new);
```

Answer (score 1):

If it's possible, try to get rid from Guava's Optional`s in your codebase.
They was designed before Oracle's Optional. In this case will be easier to use Stream API.
It's a bad practice to mix both of them.

Comment: At this point, I have been using Guava's optional throughout my code, so it will be very time consuming to replace.

Comment: @Zaryab Better take the hit now than delay it; the effort required to switch will only become greater as time passes (#technicaldebt).

Answer (score 1):

If you really don't want to swap Guava `Optional` to JDK's `Optional` (but you should), you can use helper [`toJavaUtil()`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/23.0/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Optional.html#toJavaUtil--) method and operate on its API:

```
guavaOptional.toJavaUtil()
    .map(obj -> obj.createNewObj())
    .orElseThrow(IOException::new);
```

**EDIT:**
If your `createNewObj()` method throws checked exception (here: `IOException`), you obviously won't be able to put in in lambda expression without wrapping it with unchecked exception first (eg. [`UncheckedIOExcpetion`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/UncheckedIOException.html)).

Answer (score 0):

There is `orEsleThrow` method using with Optional. Try this:

```
NewObject obj = Optional.ofNullable(objFromDatabase)
  .map(o -> o.createNewObj())
  .orElseThrow(IOException::new)
```

Comment: `->`, not `=>`.

Comment: `.map(o -> o.createNewObj())` won't compile because `obj.createNewObj(); //throws IOException`.

Comment: I am trying to think of a way to return the newObj object. Sorry if this wasn't clear in the OP, will edit to reflect this.

Comment: Thank @AndyTurner and Antot for notification. My answer may not satisfy the question